# How can I get a recovery mode on my Xperia device (which has no /recovery/ partition)?

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode, sony-xperia-l

As a developer, I need to flash custom recovery like ClockWorkMod Recovery or TWRP. I have a Sony Xperia L, But I found out that Xperia devices are not supported by these custom recoveries as they don't have a recovery partion. Is this true and if so how can I make it possible to load this custom recovery on my phone.

Is there any alternative way to do so?
Besides the way of flashing a custom kernel?

Comment: You may want to check the [official TWRP page for the Xperia Z](http://teamw.in/project/twrp2/187). It has notes that will help you get it running.

Comment: I have a Xperia L.

Comment: I have checked CWM and TWRP these both don't have support for Xperia L.

Comment: I'd recommend that you [edit] your question and add that information to it. Also look [over here~](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2499061). It's the same basic idea that the TWRP page describes for the Xperia Z.

Answer (score 5):

Sony Xperia Devices use a recovery-in-boot arrangement. While you can't simply flash a version of TWRP or CWM, you can flash a *kernel* that includes what you need.

For the Xperia L, you can flash the [Phanton Kernel](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2499061), which includes CWM.

There is **no other way** to do get CWM or TWRP without flashing a new kernel.

Comment: Yes I knew that but Thank You anyways.

Comment: Any particular reason you're asking the question when you already know the answer?

Comment: Yes my question was about flashing a recovey without habing to flash a kernel.

Comment: @coolhz Ah. I'd recommend [editing](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/59354/edit) your question to include that tidbit. In its current state, the question does not specify that.

Comment: I am doing that sorry I thought I might get better answers if i don't specify that

Comment: The answer to that question, however, is simple: there is no way to get CWM or TWRP without flashing a new kernel.